# If the numbers from 1 to 4321 were written out, how many times would the digit '5' appear?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have figured out the answer for this program, however I don't really understand what does backslush means in here.

I tried to remove the backslush, then the program print all of numbers from 1 to 4321, but it did not grep how many times number 5 appear.

When I put backslush, it just show the number how many time number 5 appear.

here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
seq 4321 | \
while read -n1 digit; do
 echo $digit
done | grep -c 5
```

Comment: Well doesn't `5` appear 10-times per `100`? So simply dividing by `((4321 / 10))` gives `432` times -- right? (integer division intentional)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You don't seem to be counting all the 5's in 50, 51, 52, 53, ... 59.

Comment: Well I'll Be... There are about 9 more of them suckers per-100 ... You are correct, so thats 19 per 100 `:)` (and then you would need to figure out whether the final was less than 50)

Comment: And 55 is two times.

Comment: And there are 100 more from 500 to 599

Comment: Wait, you don't get to count him twice? Do you? He's still in the 10-per 100 and then you add 9 more per-100 to account for `50-54` and `56-59`.(checking where you end up so you don't add 50's group where not needed) (OH -- a literal 2-5's.. I got you) This got uglier quick...

Comment: I ran your code with and without backslash and got the same results: `1262`

Comment: @smac89, yes right it is of no use of here, if there would have been long line on which we want to look it in a elegant way then we use it usually.

Comment: `seq 4321 | grep '5' | sed 's/5[^5]*5/5\n5/g' | wc -l` and I still just get 1258 which is about 4 short.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks for sharing this sir. Just want to take your view wouldn't approach of `awk` in my answer will be easier sir, just want to take your view sir.

Comment: I like it. `gsub` is better at replacing each character in a field and returning the replacement count than `sed` is in this case. The problem I have with `sed` is the multiple replacements with intervening characters. I think `awk` is the way to to go.

Comment: Just `grep -o 5 | wc -l` would do the same thing much more elegantly. Ideally `grep -oc 5` but at least GNU `grep` doesn't behave this way (there's an open bug since many years).

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
   $ seq 4321 | tr -Cd 5 | wc -c

    1262
```

which deletes all the chars but `5` and count the result

Comment: Ok that's also very clever....

Answer (score 1):

Usually back slashes when they are put after a command then it means we are telling program that line still continuing and should be considered as a same line commands execution. Usually we do so to make program cleaner(in the way one shouldn't see a LONG line which is keep continuing and shows like a non readable form).

Coming to your code now:

You need not to use `\` after `seq` command since you are using `|` and `while` could be mentioned in new line. Moreover your code is not in a long line so it may not be required and should run without it too.

I tested your code without `\` and it worked fine for me.

IMHO you need not to use `while` loop for this task, you could directly do:

```
seq 4321 | awk '{sum+=gsub(/5/,"&")} END{print sum}'
```

Try it out if this helps you(if I have got your requirement correctly), this should be faster than a loop and then using grep option.

Comment: That would only count `55` once, not twice. He's using `read -n1` to split it into separate characters.

Comment: @Barmar, Thank you sir for letting know, I thought -c option will take care of it you are right I tested it and it wouldn't. I added an awk program now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep you can do like this:

```
$ seq 4321 | grep -o 5 | wc -l
1262
$
```

---

According to grep's manual:

> `-o, --only-matching`
>
> > Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, **with each such part on a  separate  output line**.